# Assigned object to another object and preserve original data?

Tags: javascript

I co ordinates stored as an object and have duplicated the data so i have a copy before the co ordinates change. But the problem is, when I change the co ordinates both copies change to the new version and I lose the original.

So i create it like this:

```
myObj          = {};
myObj.position = {'x':12,'y':24};
myObj.startPos = myObj.position;
```

So if i change `myObj.position`, I don't want `myObj.startPos` to change. What is the simplest way to prevent this from occurring?

Comment: also you can `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))`

Comment: The question itself is asked a little differently than the duplicate, but the answers will surely just be duplicates of that question, so better to just close and reference the canonical question on the subject of cloning objects.

Comment: For your specific use-case (you shouldn't have ran into this problem) why not: `function MyObj(x,y){ this.position={'x':x, 'y':y}; this.startPos={'x':x, 'y':y}; } myObj=new MyObj(12, 24);` ? Alternatively replace `myObj.startPos = myObj.position;` with `myObj.startPos = {'x':myObj.position.x, 'y':myObj.position.y};` Both of which are going to be a lot faster than trying to clone the object (as explained in other answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that assigning object doesn't make a copy of it. Instead it is something called a reference for which reason when you change other, the other changes too. You should see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/1744702) answer about how to most efficiently copy an object in JavaScript.

If you are using any library such as jQuery you can do

```
myObj.startPos = jQuery.extend({}, myObj.position);
```

Underscore.js

```
myObj.startPos = _.clone(myObj.position);
```

Prototype.js

```
myObj.startPos = Object.clone(myObj.position);
```

Plain JavaScript function to achieve the same thing

```
function clone(obj) {
    if(obj == null || typeof(obj) != 'object')
        return obj;

    var temp = obj.constructor(); // changed

    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

and then use

```
myObj.startPos = clone(myObj.position);
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to assign the data rather than a reference? Assume that position isn't hard coded so i couldn't just type it in.

Comment: Updated the answer to contain link into that question with tens of answers describing different ways.